# Unset Multidimensional array in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm retrieving all rows from a table in database to display them in a datatables client side, with the data and respective actions. It isn't relevant but i'm using laravel. This is what i am doing:

```
$allItems = $model::withTrashed()->get();
$allRows = array();
foreach ($allItems as $item) {

        $allRows[] = array(
            $item->id,
            $item->name,
            $item->category->name,
            $item->url,
            strftime('%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M', $item->updated),
            'actions' => array(
                'view' => array(
                    'href' => $this->_mainTable. '/view/' .$item->id,
                ),
                'delete' => array(
                    'href' => $this->_mainTable. '/delete/' .$item->id,
                    'modal' => array(
                        'question' => 'Delete job:',
                        'name' => $item->name. '?',
                        'advice_phrase' => '',
                        'btn_confirm' => 'Delete',
                        'class_phrase' => '',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );

        if($item->trashed()) {
            unset(end($allRows)['actions']['delete']);
            dd(end($allRows)['actions']);
        }
}
```

It's isn't giving me any error, and on the `var_dum()` -> ( `dd(end($allRows)['actions'])` ), inside the if it's still showing the delete action. I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Can you show what you are getting in `$allItems`  and which version of laravel you are using  ?

Comment: `$allItems` are the rows retrieved from the table, including the soft deleted ones, that is working fine. I don't think the problem is laravel, the condition is working fine, the unset isn't. I'm using laravel 5.2.

Comment: `unset(end($allRows)['actions']['delete']);` changed it as 
`$lastRow = end($allRows) unset($lastRow['actions']['delete']);`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
$allItems = $model::withTrashed()->get();
$allRows = array();
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
    $delete = array();
    if (!$item->trashed()) {
        $delete = array(
            'action_table' => $this->_mainTable,
            'href' => $this->_mainTable . '/view/' . $item->id,
            'modal' => array(
                'question' => 'Delete job:',
                'name' => $item->name . '?',
                'advice_phrase' => '',
                'btn_confirm' => 'Delete',
                'class_phrase' => '',
            ),
        );
    }

    $allRows[] = array(
        $item->id,
        $item->name,
        $item->category->name,
        $item->url,
        strftime('%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M', $item->updated),
        'actions' => array(
            'view' => array(
                'action_table' => $this->_mainTable,
                'href' => $this->_mainTable . '/view/' . $item->id,
            ),
            'delete' => $delete,
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: I know several ways to achive this i just wanted to know why this way isn't working. This Anwser wouldn't work because it gives *undefined index href* on delete action.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand. Do you want to only show actions view? If so, do not add the action delete to the array $allItems.

Comment: Well some rows have the delete actions, just the rows `soft deleted ` ( `$item->trashed()`, which returns a bool ) haven't

Comment: Try to see which items have been removed temporarily

`echo $item->trashed();`

Maybe Laravel not "know" recognize.

I can not see errors in the code, so I assume that will be the Framework.

Answer (score 0):

This seens redundant,i've been able to achive this:

```
$allItems = $model::withTrashed()->get();
$allRows = array();
foreach ($allItems as $key => $item) {

    $allRows[] = array(
        $item->id,
        $item->name,
        $item->category->name,
        $item->url,
        strftime('%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M', $item->updated),
        'actions' => array(
            'view' => array(
                'href' => $this->_mainTable. '/view/' .$item->id,
            ),
            'delete' => array(
                'href' => $this->_mainTable. '/delete/' .$item->id,
                'modal' => array(
                    'question' => 'Delete job:',
                    'name' => $item->name. '?',
                    'advice_phrase' => '',
                    'btn_confirm' => 'Delete',
                    'class_phrase' => '',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );

    if($item->trashed()) {
        unset($allRows[$key]['actions']['delete']);
        dd(end($allRows)['actions']);
    }
}
```